# Solve Resharper Error in C#

Tags: c#, resharper, image-scanner

I Use VSTwain Component To Scan Images With Scanner.How Can I Solve Flowing Error?

**After Edit:**
My Application Compile And Run Correctly,But Resharper show the following error. When I write "VSTwaint1." in Visual Studio, Red Methods Can Not Show In Vs. But My Software work Correctly.
[image]

Comment: Instead of an unintelligible image, post the actual error text.

Comment: Did you exit Visual Studio and restarted it? R# then re-reads the assemblies. I have seen similar problems (after changing dll on the filesystem) that got fixed by a restart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need to import the namespace with the right `using` directive.

From the examples, I would say this is:

```
using VSTWAINLib;
```

---

Seeing as the issue is with ReSharper only, there are several things to try:

- Restart Visual Studio. ReSharper may have simply gotten out of sync.
- Clear the ReSharper cache - it might have stale data that didn't get regenerated. ReSharper --> Options --> General --> Clear Caches

Comment: Not This :-( . Please Help me :-(

Comment: @hosseinsinohe - Provide more detail please. What is the error you are seeing.

Comment: Please See Top Of Page.I Edit My Question

Comment: @hosseinsinohe - Did you try my suggestion.

Comment: @hosseinsinohe - If your application works, what's the problem? Just reshaper showing these as errors?

Comment: @hosseinsinohe - Answer updated with possible fixes for the ReSharper issue.